# read sms from emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

Unable to read sms from emulator. I need to be able to get the "body" of the sms into a string to show in a TextView or EditView. I am not trying to use the "onRecieve" sms, but rather to read an sms. I Can send to emulator via DDMS Devices Emulator Control(Windows7) or by using 2 emulators, ie sending from port 5554 to port 5556. The message shows up in the emulator, but when I try to read the sms, the cursor.getCount() only returns O, even though the "body" (ie sms text) is displayed on the emulator. I think the cursor.getCount() must equal 1 or greater to be able to read the sms, but it only = 0. What can I do to make the emulator show a cursor.getCount() > 0, and allow me to actually read the body of the sms? ie how to make the following code work. When using the emulator, the count says it equals 0, even though I have sent an sms:

```
if(count>0){
   if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
    txtLastSMS.setText(body);
   }
 }
```

Here is the pertinent code:

```
    Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");    
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,     null);                                   
    String body = null;
    if (cursor != null)
       try
       {
          int count = cursor.getCount();
          if(count>0){
             if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
             body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
             txtLastSMS.setText(body);
          }
        }   
      }
      finally{ cursor.close();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `startManagingCursor`:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,     null);
startManagingCursor(cursor);
```

Comment: I tried this,  but a line through was immediately drawn through this method and the error message: the method has been 'deprecated to "onCreate".

Comment: Also I will mention that I have added the READ_SMS permission to the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Deprecated means it is still working but there is a better implementation (CusorLoader). Is the method inside your Activity?

Comment: You could replace it with cursor.open() then at the end you must use cursor.close()

Comment: The method was inside the activity. Is the most up-to-date method to read an sms: read the  message using SMSManage.createFromPdu() rather than using : cursor = getContentResolver().query(Content_uri, null,null,null,null)  ????

Comment: I have now been able to read SMSs using Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSuri,null,null,null,null). A11)fter Cursor cursor =..., I just used: while(cur.moveToNetx()){ aString = cur.getString(11)}.  Which technique is the preferred way to read SMS?